# Open modal web page from another web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I am creating a form in a PHP file. In the form I have a link. On clicking the link I want to open a web page or PHP page as a modal window.

Below is the form in test1.php which I want to create.

```
<form action="test.php" name="form" METHOD="POST">
    <a href="#"  onclick="window.open('test.php','popup','scrollbars=1,width=620,height=620,top=50,left=200')" title="Listbox" class="toplinks1">Open Link</a>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

The above form has a link, "Open Link", which does open test.php in another window. But I can access the test1.php while the test.php is open.

I need to open test.php as a modal window.

Comment: your trying to open another file???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem,

```
<a href="http://wikipedia.com/" class="test">comment #1</a><br>
<a href="http://ebay.com/" class="test">comment #2</a><br>
<a href="http://ask.com/" class="test" >comment #3</a><br>
<div id="somediv" title="this is a dialog" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="thedialog" width="350" height="350"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test").click(function () {
            $("#thedialog").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
            $("#somediv").dialog({
                width: 400,
                height: 450,
                modal: true,
                close: function () {
                    $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also check the JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/qp7NP/.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following method to open an external file on the same page:

```
<body>
    <p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="mobilepost.php">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
    <p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="tablet.html">Tablets</a></p>
    <p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="accessories.html">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>

    <div class="page">
        // Your external file will load in this area
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.reveal').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).attr('href');
                $('.page').load(link);
                $('.reveal').hide();
            $(this).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```